# Assigning variable to $scope inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive:

```
<users-table user="{{ session.user }}"></users-table>
```

`session.user` is an object containing several key-value pairs.

I have a directive:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('users-table', function($scope) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            currentUser: "=user"
        },
        templateUrl: '/js/directives/templates/users-table.html',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            console.log(currentUser);
            $scope.user = currentUser;
        } // link
    }; // return
}]);
```

At this stage, I'm simply trying to confirm that it's wired-up correctly, by outputting the `$scope.user` object in the template:

/js/directives/templates/users-table.html:

```
{{ user }}
```

But this doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong here in this simple directive?

Debugging steps I've already gone through:

1. Checked that the file is loaded correctly.
2. Checked output of `session.user` (this is correct just before directive element).

Edit: it seems that the link function isn't even being called because the `currentUser` is not being logged to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct assignment is:

```
<users-table user="session.user"></users-table>
```

`{{ session.user }}` would have a single way binding: `currentUser: "@user"`

Also, as already stated, the assignment should be:

```
    $scope.user = $scope.currentUser;
```

And lastly, the directive should be declared as:

```
.directive('usersTable'
```

This because the directives want a camel case value in the declaration and dash delimited attributes in the html

Here is a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wkvmt5m7/2/

Comment: I thought that might be the case, so I tried that, but still the same result - i.e. no output.

Comment: Thanks, your edit regarding the naming was the main issue - thanks for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `currentUser` anywhere in your `link` function. So it sits as an undefined (and undeclared) variable.

Creating isolate scope as you have done pre-populates the scope inside the link function to connect or copy (or whatever) from the parent scope. So you really need to do:

```
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, User) {
        console.log($scope.currentUser);
        $scope.user = $scope.currentUser;
    }
```

The isolate scope

```
scope: {
   currentUser: '=user'
}
```

sets up `scope.currentUser` in your link function to be `scope.user` from the parent.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've corrected it but still have the same problem. I'm thinking that my directive may not be wired up to the app correctly.

Comment: Put in a jsfiddle and share it, happy to look. I have a basic jsfiddle with all of the angular loaded in, so you can just modify the html and js, at http://jsfiddle.net/m0q28vjc/